# Create a File with Touch on a specific Directory

Tags: unix

I want a create a file with a specific extension(.done). I am using the command touch. Something Like:

```
touch `basename $UNZIPFILE`".done"
```

It's creating the file but in current directory. I want to create this file in a specific directory. Is there a option to provide the directory ?

I checked : http://ss64.com/bash/touch.html , but could not figure out.

I can think of one option is before this command I can do a cd requiredDIR

Is there any other way, I can specify the Directory on the same command, so that I dont have to change the Directory?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply prepend the directory variable to the file you are touching.

```
touch "$MYDIR/$(basename $UNZIPFILE).done"
```

If the directory doesn't exist, you need to create it.

```
mkdir -p "$MYDIR" && touch "$MYDIR/$(basename $UNZIPFILE).done"
```

(It's also better to use `$(command)` syntax instead of backticks for command substitution.)